# Editing data without removing previously added. Django using 'forms.Form'

Tags: python, django, forms

How can I edit data without deleting what has been added before. In my situation, I want to use forms.Form which looks like this

```
class SecondForm(forms.Form):
    data_1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, label="")
    data_2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, label="")
    data_3 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, label="")
```

In my views.py

```
id = #some object number
if request.method =="POST":
    second_form = SecondForm(request.POST)
    if second_form.is_valid():
        cd = second_form.cleaned_data
        object = Valuation(pk=object_id)
        object.data_1 = cd['data_1']
        object.data_2 = cd['data_2']
        object.data_3 = cd['data_3']
        object.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:valuation_third', args=[forwarding]))
else:
    second_form = SecondForm()
```

In this situation, if my model looks like this:

```
class Valuation(models.Model):
    data_added_before = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    data_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    data_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    data_3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

Every time a field 'data_added_before' it's cleaned. How to avoid it. So that the information added earlier in this field has been preserved. And new data from the current form added to existing ones.

### Edit

[image]

**Template.html**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
          <form action="." method="post">
          <div class="">
            <h2 class="h3 text-primary font-weight-normal mb-4">More information></h2>
          </div>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>data_1 name</p>
            {{ second_form.data_1|as_crispy_field }}
            <p>data_2 name</p>
            {{ second_form.data_2|as_crispy_field }}
            <p>data_3 name</p>
            {{ second_form.data_3|as_crispy_field }}
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                <form>
                  <input class="btn btn-text btn-text-secondary" type="button" value="before" onclick="history.back()">
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                <div class="text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">next <i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-lg"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>
```

Comment: What you mean by ***"Every time a field 'data_added_before' it's cleaned"***?

Comment: I added presentations of the view from django-admin above. This happens after sending the form.

Comment: Your form is not having the field `data_added_before`, how are you gettting it in template ?

Comment: I added above my tempalte.

Comment: Fill first data submit, instantiate and fill the form with second data, render it. It would work